# Fluent NHibernate AutoMapping PrimaryKey Property Name is not "Id"

Tags: c#, fluent-nhibernate, primary-key, automapping

I am trying to migrate to Fluent NHibernate and have the following problem :(

I have a a number of classes called in the manner of CompanyXXXXXX, which all have a PrimaryKey of "CompanyId" which is of type Company.

A HBM Mapping file which i was using until name was this:

```
  <class name="CompanyAccounting" table="Company_Accounting" >
    <id column="CompanyID" type="Int32">
      <generator class="foreign">
        <param name="property">Company</param>
      </generator>
    </id>
    <one-to-one name="Company" constrained="true" />
  </class>
```

The entity is as follows:

```
public class CompanyAccounting
{
    public virtual Company Company {get;set;}        
}
```

Is it possible to use some sort of AutoMapping feature, as i have a dozen of these classes and there is likely to be more.

I have tried the following:

```
    public class CustomPrimaryKeyConvention : IIdConvention
    {
        public void Apply(IIdentityInstance instance)
        {
            var type = instance.EntityType;
            if (type.Name.StartsWith("Company") && type.Name.Length > 7)
            {
                instance.CustomType(typeof(Company));
                instance.Column("CompanyId");
            } 
            else
            {
                instance.Column(instance.EntityType.Name + "Id");
            }
        }
    }
```

**EDIT :** But my If(...)[For "CompanyAccounting" Type] doesn't even get hit. Any suggestions?

Exception:

```
The entity 'CompanyAccounting' doesn't have an Id mapped. 
Use the Id method to map your identity property. For example: Id(x => x.Id).
```

Answer (score 1):

Did you register that convention with Fluent Nhibernate?

You should have something along the lines

```
AutoMap.AssemblyOf<CompanyAccounting>()
       .Conventions.AddFromAssemblyOf<CustomPrimaryKeyConvention>()
```

Comment: Hi forgot to mention that it doesnt get hit for CompanyAccounting, it gets hit for previous, classes, but it doesnt call the method Apply for CompanyAccounting, the exception gets hit beforehand.

Comment: So your convention works for other classes but not CompanyAccounting? Is CompanyAccounting in the same assembly as classes that it does work for?

Comment: yes... i think the problem is because CompanyAccounting has no public Id{get;set;}, but i don't know how i can tell automapper not to look for Id field, but instead use Company field.

Comment: Yes answers which question(s)?

Comment: @Chris sorry, Yes CompanyAccounting is in the same assembly as the other classes and the same namespace. And the convention works for other classes, but when i step through the debug, it crashes as soon as it tries to do the initialisation for CompanyAccounting

Comment: I'm not really sure I think you should try the FNH group.